# Colouring by category in a pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing a continuous number for  the cumulative sum in a column called `cont_col` and a category column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cont = np.random.rand(100)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=cont)

df = df.sort_values(by=0)

df['quartile'] = pd.qcut(df[0], 4, labels=False)

cumsum = df[0].cumsum()
cumsum = cumsum.to_frame()
cumsum[0].plot(kind='bar', color='k')
```

I would like to plot the same data, but this time coloured by the quartile column.

I can do it with the following code:

```
def colourise(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 'k'
    elif x == 1:
        return 'r'
    elif x == 2:
        return 'g'
    else:
        return 'b'

df['colour'] = df['quartile'].apply(colourise)
cumsum = df[0].cumsum()
cumsum = cumsum.to_frame()
cumsum[0].plot(kind='bar', color=df['colour'].tolist())
```

I just wonder if there is a more general way - in particular, one which didn't depend on the number of qtiles I create.

Comment: Still, you must have some sort of category in hand?

Comment: aslo, it helps if you can reduce your sample to, say 4-10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't particularly care about the colors, create a mapping with one of the seaborn color palettes. This way you just need to specify the column, not the number of categories or colors. If you have many ordered categories, consider switching to a sequential palette.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def map_color(df, col):
    color_d = dict(zip(df[col].unique(), sns.color_palette("hls", df[col].nunique())))
    df['color'] = df[col].map(color_d)
    return df

df  = map_color(df, 'quartile')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
df.assign(y=df[0].cumsum()).plot(kind='bar', y='y', ax=ax, color=df.color.tolist(),
                                 legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dictionary of your color mappings.

```
color_map = {
    0:'k',
    1:'r',
    2:'g'
}
```

Then, use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['colour'] = df['quartile'].map(color_map).fillna('b')
```